# PHP - What it means whole code inside {}

Tags: php, wordpress

Following code, I saw on a WordPress theme.

All code was written inside `{}`. I have no idea what it is,

What it means?

```
<?php 
{
    $html = '';
    if ( 'right' === $sidebar_pos || 'left' === $sidebar_pos ) {
        $html = '<div class="';
        if ( is_active_sidebar( 'right-sidebar' ) || is_active_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ) ) {
            $html .= 'col-md-8 content-area" id="primary">';
        } else {
            $html .= 'col-md-12 content-area" id="primary">';
        }
        echo $html; // WPCS: XSS OK.
    } elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'right-sidebar' ) && is_active_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ) ) {
        $html = '<div class="';
        if ( 'both' === $sidebar_pos ) {
            $html .= 'col-md-6 content-area" id="primary">';
        } else {
            $html .= 'col-md-12 content-area" id="primary">';
        }
        echo $html; // WPCS: XSS OK.
    } else {
        echo '<div class="col-md-12 content-area" id="primary">';
    }
}
```

Comment: This markup is valid, I'm not sure it really means anything special.

Comment: Is there more to that file? If that's in a stand-alone file I'm guessing it's because that file is called elsewhere in the theme.

Answer (score 0):

what you have inside `{}` is called a statement-group according to the PHP manual.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.intro.php

> Any PHP script is built out of a series of statements. A statement can
>   be an assignment, a function call, a loop, a conditional statement or
>   even a statement that does nothing (an empty statement). Statements
>   usually end with a semicolon. In addition, statements can be grouped
>   into a statement-group by encapsulating a group of statements with
>   curly braces. A statement-group is a statement by itself as well. The
>   various statement types are described in this chapter.

To answer your question, It doesn't have a very special meaning in the code you have provided. With the {} brace block or without the block it will behave similar.

Comment: Can you please relate is to the question asked?

Comment: I was doing further reading and editing after reading the question for the second time.

Answer (score -1):

To the best of my knowledge it does not have any special meaning in terms of PHP syntax beyond allowing a way to group blocks of code. While doing this it will impose limitations. For instance, you cannot define namespaces and constants inside {}.